# Не компилируется код C++

Tags: c++

Код:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Array
{
    int n;
    int *arr = new int[n];
public:
    Array(int n) : n(n)
    { }

    Array operator[](int);
    void display()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            cout << arr[i] << " ";
        }
    }
    int get_n()
    {
        return n;
    }
    ~Array()
    {
        delete[] arr;
    }
};

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    Array a1(12), a2(5);
    for (int i = 0; i < 12 ; i++)
    {
        a1[i] = i * 2;
    }
    a1.display();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

Array Array::operator[](int j)
{
    return arr[j];
}
```

Где здесь ошибка? Что-то в выделении памяти?

Comment: Почему "не компилируется"? VC++ 2017 скомпилировал. Какая именно ошибка **компиляции**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ошибки при **компиляции** тут нет.
Ошибка при **выполнении** - да, это есть.

Что вы возвращаете тут?

```
Array Array::operator[](int j)
{
    return arr[j];
}
```

Новый объект `Array` с количеством членов, равным значению `arr[j]`. А потом пытаетесь присвоить ему что-то - с помощью генерируемого по умолчанию оператора присваивания. Т.е. делаете полную ерунду, которую долго расписывать (да и нужно ли?)...

Вы явно хотели следующее:

```
int& Array::operator[](int j)
{
    return arr[j];
}
```

Comment: уже заметил что вместо `int` написал `Array`, но еще вопрос в том, зачем нам ссылка ( `&`) как тип возвращаемого значения?

Comment: Иначе вы не сможете выполнить присвоение `a1[i] = i * 2;`

Comment: т.е. оно возвращает именно переменную, а не константу?

Comment: Ссылка? l-значение :), т.е. нечто, чему можно выполнить присвоение. Просто `int` - давало бы r-значение, присваивать которому нельзя, ну, как бессмысленно присвоение `2 = 5`...

Answer (score 3):

Вы инициализируете указатель не в конструкторе, а сразу в обьявлении

```
class Array
{
    int n;
    int *arr = new int[n];
//...
```

естественно у вас будет и ошибка компиляции...
Может вы просто проявили невнимательность, но нужно так:

```
class Array
{
    int n;
    int *arr;
public:
    Array(int n) : n(n), arr( new int[n] )
    { }
//...
};
```

Comment: Извините, а какая разница где его инициализировать?

Comment: Разница в том, что просто в языке С++  не существует такого способа инициализации кроме константных статистических интегральных типов, таких как  const static int  m = 5; ...  Постольку поскольку  создает обьект именно конструктор, а   статический обьект m  одинаков  для всех обьектов этого класса .  Как вы представляете инварианты класса,  или по вашему для чего вообше существует конструктор ?...  Вам стоит получше изучать язык, чтоб не задавать такой вопрос:  какая разница....?